# How to center 3 divs in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hi I want to center 3 divs to the middle of the page, I have each of them floating left so that they are side by side however I want these to be central to the page.

I have them in wrappers with a width of `100%` and have tried to use `margin:0px auto` in order to center this this doesn't work but `width:100%` or `width:auto`, however if I specify a width this seems to center however I don't want to specify a width to my wrapper I want it to be the size of the page.

I'm not entirely sure in regards to what I've done wrong. So any input and a fresh pair of eyes would be fantastic!

My code is below or you can view a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aS3Ec/1/)

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */


/********************************
    * CSS Reset                     *
    *********************************/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/********************************
    * Main Styles                   *
    *********************************/

.header {
  background: #062141;
  /* Old browsers */
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #062141), color-stop(25%, #0f2f4e), color-stop(62%, #2b5878), color-stop(99%, #2b5878));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#062141', endColorstr='#2b5878', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-8 */
  height: 100px;
}

.header .wrap {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.header .wrap .img_1,
.header .wrap .img_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 5px;
}

.header .wrap .img_1 {
  left: 0;
}

.header .wrap .img_2 {
  right: 0;
}

.header h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "ufonts com perpetua 2";
  line-height: 100px;
}

#sjplogo {
  float: left;
}

#sslogo {
  float: right;
}

footer {
  background: #062141;
  /* Old browsers */
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #062141), color-stop(25%, #0f2f4e), color-stop(62%, #2b5878), color-stop(99%, #2b5878));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#062141', endColorstr='#2b5878', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-8 */
  height: 100px;
  postion: absoutle;
  bottom: 0;
}

.maincontent p {
  font-family: "ufonts com perpetua 2";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #001838;
  margin: 10px;
}


/**STICKY FOOTER**/

.fixedfooter {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
  /*gradient*/
  background: #062141;
  /* Old browsers */
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #062141), color-stop(25%, #0f2f4e), color-stop(62%, #2b5878), color-stop(99%, #2b5878));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #062141 0%, #0f2f4e 25%, #2b5878 62%, #2b5878 99%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#062141', endColorstr='#2b5878', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-8 */
}

.maincontent {
  height: 1000px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.maincontentWrapper {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.topWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.center {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="wrap">
      <span class="img_1"><img src="imgs/sjplogo.png" id="sjplogo"/></span>
      <h2>Website Service</h2>
      <span class="img_2"><img src="imgs/sslogo.png" id="sslogo"/></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="maincontent">
    <div class="maincontentWrapper">
      <div class="topWrapper">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="center"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
      <!--End topWrapper-->

      <div class="bottomWrapper">
        <div class="leftBottom"></div>
        <div class="rightBottom"></div>
      </div>
      <!--End bottomWrapper-->

    </div>
    <!-- End maincontentWrapper-->

  </div>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the `.topWrapper` div to have a `text-align:center` rule, then remove the `float:left` from those three divs (.left, .center, and .right) and replace them with `display:inline-block`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aS3Ec/3/)

```
.topWrapper {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.left {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.center {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.right {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

Comment: Just beware the spacing problem with `inline-block`. Whitespace in the HTML adds space between `inline-block` elements in some browsers, so if you want your margin between the elements to be *exactly* 20px, you'll have to remove whitespace from your HTML or change the `font-size` of the parent to 0 so spaces don't take up width.